# WF CodeActivity after WCF SendReply Activity

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I created a WCF Service with Workflow Foundation 4.0, with ReceiveAndSendReply activity block.

After the Send response Activity I placed a custom Code Activity to do stuff.
When I debug with a custom Unit Test that calls this service, it doesn't stop on breakpoints placed on Code Activity, but ends on Send response.

Have you any idea?

The process ends on Send Response activity and doesn't continue with flow on DoOther activity?

No exceptions are thrown.[image: my WF sample]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Troubleshooting Workflow Services with diagnostic logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/12/16/troubleshooting-workflow-services-with-diagnostic-logging.aspx)

Comment: Yes you should -- out of all of the blogs, tools, and opinions on the internet -- nothing has saved me more time and pain than this and it's just a couple lines in the Web.config!  Thanks @RonJacobs!